# Add a label to a Line graph indicating the name of the variable in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a created in tableau 2 a graph with 2 lines and I need to use Red when value<0.

To make clear what variable (Calculated field attached example[image] screenshot), i would like to add a label on the graph indicating the name of the variable.

I have the same graph for different languages, so this should be shown on all visuals with these 2 lines.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could either show the legend or create a calculated field to only show the name on the last data point, then put that field in the Label shelf alongside the numbers. As your calculated field only returns a value on the last occurence, it'll be null for all other values.

Your calculcation will be something like:

```
IF LAST()=O THEN [dimension] END
```